# dropdown navigation menu text's line breaks not working after adjusting div size

Tags: html, css

i was working on a nav menu based around a code from w3school- it was a fixed 100% width sidebar navigation menu. after adjusting it a bit i decided i wanted it to not be 100& and to be next to my other main body div.

But after adjusting it to be in the right place, the text/nav links are in a line and not on seperate lines as they had just been a moment before. i am having trouble understanding why, and what i can do to fix it.

Image of what i mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6yi7.jpg

below is the code for the sidebar (i can provide for the other divs too but i think its just the sidebar that is the problem?)

"Old code" is the original code for the full size sidebar.

```
/* DROPDOWN SIDEBAR STUFF */

.sidenav {
            /* OLD CODE
            background-color: rgba(0,109,165, .8);
            font-size: 14px;
            border: 5px dashed rgba(0,208,129);
            color: #5afba2;  
            text-align: left;
            font-family: monospace;
            border-radius: 10px;
            
              height: 100%;
              width: 200px;
              position: fixed;
              z-index: 1;
              top: 0;
              left: 0;
              overflow-x: hidden;
              padding-top: 20px;
            */
    
                background-color: rgba(0,109,165, .8);
            font-size: 14px;
            border: 3px dashed rgba(0,208,129);
            border-radius: 10px;
            color: #5afba2;   
            font-family: monospace;
            overflow-y: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            
            display: flex;
            float:left;
            justify-content: space-between;
            height: 700px;
            width: 200px;
            
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin-left: 300px;
            padding-left: 15px;
            padding-right: 15px;
            padding-top: 15px;
            padding-bottom: 25px;
            position: ansolute;
}

/* Style the sidenav links and the dropdown button */
.sidenav a, .dropdown-btn {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
font-family: monospace;
  color: #5afba2;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.dropdown-btn {
    font-size:22px;
}

/* On mouse-over */
.sidenav a:hover, .dropdown-btn:hover {
  color: white;
}

/* Add an active class to the active dropdown button */
.active {
  background-color: none;
  color: white;
}

/* Dropdown container (hidden by default). Optional: add a lighter background color and some left padding to change the design of the dropdown content */
.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: none;
  padding-left: 8px;
    font-size:12px;
}

/* Optional: Style the caret down icon */
.fa-caret-down {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

/* Some media queries for responsiveness */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

and the HTML for the sidebar

```
           <div class="sidenav">
  <button class="dropdown-btn">GENERAL 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
  </div>
  <button class="dropdown-btn">FANDOM 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
  </div>
  <button class="dropdown-btn">ORIGINAL 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
  </div>
  <button class="dropdown-btn">SUPPORT 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
  </div>
<button class="dropdown-btn">OUTGOING 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

let me know if anymore information is needed.

Comment: I think display: flex; is making all your buttons inside of .sidenav line up next to eachother. Just try taking that line out.

Comment: oh thank god, what a simple mistake a fix. well, it was just that it seems. didnt realize display:flex did that too!

Answer (score 0):

"display: flex;" is making all  inside of class "sidenav" display in a line. You can learn more about display flex here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox